# Filtering data only if match with all get elements

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a filter by comparing the elements of my table to the parameters that I pass in `$_GET`

```
if(isset($_GET['skills']) && !empty($_GET['skills']))
            {
                $memberModel->where("t1.id IN(SELECT TMS.member_id FROM `".memberSkillModel::factory()->getTable()."` AS `TMS` WHERE `TMS`.skill_id IN(".join(",", $_GET['skills'])."))");
            }
```

with this query, I display result sets if there is a match with any of the given values.
Can I display result sets only if there is a match with all of the given values but no with any of them ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's no duplicate entry? Could you try some think like this

```
if (isset($_GET['skills']) && 
    is_array($_GET['skills']) &&
    !empty($_GET['skills'])) {
    
    $skills = $_GET['skills'];
    //sanitiz
    $skills = array_map(function($i) { return intval($i); }, $skills);
    $size = count($skills);
    
    $sql = sprintf("t1.id IN (
select 
    TMS.member_id  
from
    `%s` as `TMS` 
where 
    `TMS`.skill_id in (%s)
group by 
    TMS.member_id
having 
    count(*) = %d
    )", 
    $memberSkillModel::factory()->getTable(),
    join(",", $skills),
    $size);
    
    $memberModel->where($sql);
}
```

Comment: `join(",", $skills)` will produce invalid SQL like `IN(some_string,some other string )`. And even more, there's a door wide opened for an SQL injection in your answer.

Comment: Hello, @jared join(",", $skills)  will produce invalid SQL if are string, i think is integers. And in original the code is join(",", $_GET['skills']). Yes all version present here are note sanitized, but is not the purpose of question

Comment: Its not, and the idea in your answer seems right. But I don't think providing broken code with a security issue is more helpless than harmfull.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Now is sanitized

Comment: Applying the code i have this message Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Do have used the version with TMS.member_id , count(*)`? If yes, remove just , count(*)